# Diseño para un Select

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Estoy tratando de usar la librería Select2. Para mostrar una lista y puedan buscar en tiempo real. Pero, cuando ejecuto el código lo visualiza mal, el select lo estoy agregando en una ventana modal con bootstrap:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="formTareas" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <p class="h3">Nueva Tarea <span class="icon-tasks"></span></p>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close hint--top hint--rounded" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="<?php echo $titulo_mensaje_cerrar; ?>"><span aria-hidden="true"></span></button>                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form_row row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="asunto" placeholder="">
                            <label for="asunto"><?php echo $titulo_asunto; ?></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form_row row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input type="date" id="FechaInicio" class="form-control" value="">
                            <label for=""><?php echo $titulo_fecha_inicio; ?></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input type="time" id="HoraIInicio" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                            <label for=""><?php echo $titulo_hora_inicio; ?></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form_row row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-floating">
                            <select class="form-select" id="state">
                                 <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                 <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                                 <option value="PR">Pruebas</option>
                             </select>
                            <label for="">Asociado a</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="Agregar" class="btn btn-outline-success hint--top hint--rounded" aria-label="<?php echo $titulo_mensaje_guardart; ?>"><?php echo $titulo_agregar; ?></button>
            <button type="button" id="Modificar" class="btn btn-outline-success hint--top hint--rounded" aria-label="<?php echo $titulo_mensaje_modificart; ?>"><?php echo $titulo_modificar; ?></button>
            <button type="button" id="Borrar" class="btn btn-outline-danger hint--top hint--rounded" aria-label="<?php echo $titulo_mensaje_eliminart; ?>"><?php echo $titulo_borrar; ?></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary hint--top hint--rounded" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="<?php echo $titulo_mensaje_cerrar; ?>"><?php echo $titulo_cancelar; ?></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Código JQUERY:
$(function(){
$(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
openCcontents(event, 'general_tab');//Se posicina en la primera tab

```
            $('#formTareas').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                // Inicializar Select2
                $('#state').select2();
            });
        });
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto lo muestra mal. Adjunto pantallazo de como lo visualiza.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ https://select2.org/dropdown

Comment: Disculpa, si modifique las imágenes originales. El select lo estoy agregando dentro de un modal. Pero cuando le doy para mostrar las opciones lo visualiza como la última imagen en la edición

Comment: Procura mostrar un [repro] incluyendo el select2 y el modal. Con solo imágenes, es difícil deducir lo que sucede.

Comment: @padaleiana ya edite la pregunta.

Comment: Procurá mostrar tu problema con datos de ejemplo, como snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`). No olvides además agregar las bibliotecas (jquery, bootstrap, select2) que estás utilizando, en las versiones que las estás utilizando. La idea es descartar que sea nada más un problema de importación o de etiquetas mal cerradas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes problemas con el `z-index`, debes agregar un valor más alto:

Añade esto a tu CSS

```
.select2-container--open{
  z-index:1111;
}
```

NOTA: También debes quitar el `tabindex="-1"` en tu Modal, para que funciones el textbox de búsqueda

DEMO:

```js
$('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
         $('#state').select2();
});
```

```css
.select2-container--open{
  z-index:1111;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal"  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <select class="col-12" id="state">
          <option>1<option>
          <option>2<option>
          <option>3<option>
          <option>4<option>
          <option>5<option>
          <option>6<option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lo del z-index sería una solución rápida, pero el problema pareciera estar en otra parte. No se ve por ejemplo cómo está importando los CSS, o si tiene etiquetas mal cerradas (que lo sé de primera mano porque ya me llegó a pasar).

Comment: Muchas gracias colegas. Ambas opciones me sirvieron mucho

Answer (score 1):

Generalmente el tema de la correcta visuallización del select2 en un modal dialog se resuelve estebleciendo la propiedad `dropdownParent` del select2 a un elemento propio del modal. modificar el z-index también resuelve. En cualquier caso prueba con:

```
$('#formTareas').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
         $('select.form-select').select2({
            dropdownParent: $('#formTareas'),
         });
});
```

En este caso tomé como referencia del modal el propio elemento que conviertes en modal por su `id`, pero puedes ser más específico al body del modal por ejemplo.

Comment: Realmente es esta la respuesta. Es un [problema común](https://select2.org/troubleshooting/common-problems), tal como explica la documentación.